# In the Head First C# book, I cannot understand why 2 ifs for checking the same condition again

Tags: c#

I'm not able to understand why 2 times the same if condition is checked when the goal is to return zero if the amount is not > 0

I found this code on page 737 of the Head First C# book.

Can someone explain?

```
public int ReceiveCash(int amount) 
{

    if (amount > 0)
    {
        if (amount > 0)
        {
            Cash += amount;
            return amount;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("{0} says: {1} isn't an amount I’ll take", Name, amount);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: IMO this is probably an error

Comment: learning from head first c#,i have the 2nd and 3rd editions and in both it is the same. Cant understand the logic.

Comment: I think compiler should detect this and complain about unreachable code

Comment: also i see "else" is default and is not required to be written in c#, right?

Comment: Else is default?  No.  If you need an else statement, you put one in.  Otherwise if the if test condition fails, the code continues after the end of the if block.  Which I guess you could consider an implicit else, but else is not a default.

Comment: second `if` is unnecessary. this things happens when you copy & paste code snippets without verifying

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess (based on OP's comment about `else` being default), but the code should probably look something like this:

```
public int ReceiveCash(int amount) 
{

    if (amount > 0)
    {
        Cash += amount;
        return amount;
    }    
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} says: {1} isn't an amount I’ll take", Name, amount);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Here if the amount is greater than 0 it's added to the `Cash` variable and the amount added is returned, otherwise (else) an error message is printed to the console and 0 is returned.

Not really a good example of `if-else` in my opinion, but I don't have the book so I don't have the context of the exmaple, just the code.

Comment: That's exactly how it looks in [the version of this book that's on Google Books](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mcWDAAAAQBAJ), which says it's the 3rd Edition.